# Texto "vaza" por trás das <th> usando CSS position sticky

Tags: html, css

Estou usando `position: sticky;` no `<thead>` de uma tabela onde atribuo um cor de fundo aos `<th>`.

A minha intenção é que, ao rolar a página, o cabeçalho permaneça visível pois a tabela tem muitas linhas e isso facilita bastante a leitura dos dados.

O problema é que o texto que é rolado para cima aparece por trás dos `<th>` da tabela.

Vejam um exemplo:

```js
/*
  Este código não tem nada a ver com o problema
  é só para o HTML não ficar quilométrico.
*/
let tr = document.getElementById('replicar')
let frag = document.createDocumentFragment()
let i = 30

while (i-- > 0) { frag.appendChild(tr.cloneNode(true)) }
tr.parentElement.appendChild(frag)
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 15px;
}

th {
  background-color: #babaca;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="replicar">
      <td>Coluna 1</td>
      <td>Coluna 2</td>
      <td>Coluna 3</td>
      <td>Coluna 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Como o [Chrome não suporta](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=702927) `position: sticky` em `<thead>`, segue uma imagem:

[image: Texto vazado]

---

Eu "resolvi" meu problema aplicando um `box-shadow` no meu `<thead>` para que haja um "backdrop" que cubra o texto rolando atrás.

Segue um exemplo com o `box-shadow` em vermelho para facilitar a visualização:

```js
/*
  Este código não tem nada a ver com o problema
  é só para o HTML não ficar quilométrico.
*/
let tr = document.getElementById('replicar')
let frag = document.createDocumentFragment()
let i = 30

while (i-- > 0) { frag.appendChild(tr.cloneNode(true)) }
tr.parentElement.appendChild(frag)
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 -8px 0 8px red; /* Aqui seria branco */
}

th {
  background-color: #babaca;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="replicar">
      <td>Coluna 1</td>
      <td>Coluna 2</td>
      <td>Coluna 3</td>
      <td>Coluna 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Imagem:

[image: Com box-shadow]

---

Minha dúvida é, existe uma maneira menos gambiarra de fazer isso?

Eu deveria usar outro elemento pra poder ter um `background-color` que se sobrepusesse ao texto?

Comment: Se vc colocar top 0px e não 15px vc vai ver que resolve :)

Comment: Olá jovem, sabia que eu ia te encontrar por aqui :) Sobre o `top: 0;`, eu sei disso, mas o problema é que eu não quero que fique colado no topo. Fica ruim de ler e fica grudado na minha NavBar

Comment: Cara eu estou em um hackathon hj ai vai ser difícil parar pra testar etc, mas vc pode tentar colocando um pseudo-elemento na tabela... Isso se vc considerar isso menos gambiarra rss... Outra opção seria colocar a tabela dentro de uma div. Mas só testando pra ver o resultado

Comment: Relaxa Hugo, não tenho pressa para as resposta. Já tá funcionando legal aqui, é mais para alguém me ensinar alguma coisa mesmo.

Comment: Olha se é isso que vc precisa https://codepen.io/hugocsl/pen/LMYVyK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução que achei foi criar um [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) no meu `thead` com a mesma cor do fundo da página, dessa maneira o texto fica escondido "embaixo" do `box-shadow` criando o efeito que quero.

Como mencionado na pergunta, na minha opinião esta solução não é ideal e será marcada como a resposta correta temporariamente enquanto uma resposta melhor não for proposta, ou o bug for resolvido.

---

## Código

Estou usando vermelho como sombra para ficar mais fácil visualizar onde a sombra está, mas na prática a cor será igual a do fundo, dando a impressão que o texto some quando passa "por baixo" do cabeçalho.

```js
/*
  Este código não tem nada a ver com o problema
  é só para o HTML não ficar quilométrico.
*/
let tr = document.getElementById('replicar')
let frag = document.createDocumentFragment()
let i = 30

while (i-- > 0) { frag.appendChild(tr.cloneNode(true)) }
tr.parentElement.appendChild(frag)
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 -8px 0 8px red; /* Aqui seria branco */
}

th {
  background-color: #babaca;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="replicar">
      <td>Coluna 1</td>
      <td>Coluna 2</td>
      <td>Coluna 3</td>
      <td>Coluna 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito interessante a técnica do drop-shadow

Answer (score -3):

Talvez seria melhor utilizar:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```